# Regarding pos tagging

Tags: python, nlp, dataset, feature-selection, feature-extraction

I working on a dataset, I did the pos_tagging using nltk. Now I want to know which sequence of grammar is most common in my rows, then I want to define a chunk grammar based on a common grammar sequence. Can you please tell me how to do it in python?
Thank you

[image]

Comment: You would need to extract n-grams of POS tags for various lengths N and count their frequency.

Comment: I need to know the grammar sequence followed by most of the sentences. e.g, Noun>Verb> DT>Noun>Pronoun etc.......

Comment: Yes, as I said the first step is to compute all the POS [n-grams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) frequencies. You have several options to do this, personally I would simply code it myself (it's not very complex) but otherwise you can prepare the list of POS tags as if they are words and feed this to CountVectorizer.